# Duplicating a layer in Photoshop without 'copy' behind its name

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to duplicate a layer in Photoshop, but **I don't want the word 'copy' to automatically be added behind the layer name**.

Is there a way to turn this behaviour off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adobe forums holds some different approaches, although there isn't a formalized solution built into Photoshop.

The common solution is to duplicate so that you get the naming dialog, where you name the layer as you duplicate it.

Here is a [link to a script extension](http://ps-scripts.com/bb/viewtopic.php?p=1346) that will remove this behavior.

[Adobe Forums on this topic](http://forums.adobe.com/message/1633912#1633912)

Hope that helps.

Comment: I was too new to add the other link to the adobe forums on this topic...it's http://forums.adobe.com/message/1633912#1633912

Comment: Should be good now ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the Layers panel, open the panel menu (upper right), choose Panel Options... and uncheck:

- Add "copy" to Copied Layers and Groups